# How to count the numbers of an rpt file in python without reading the document extensively?

Tags: python, pandas, rpt

I have quite a bunch of data; More prcisely, a 8 GB rpt file;

Now before processing it I want to know how many rows there actually are - this helps me to later find out how long the processing will take etc;
Now reading an rpt file of that size in python as a whole obviously does not work so I need to read line by line; To find out the number of lines I wrote that simple python script:

```
import pandas as pd

counter=0

for line in pd.read_fwf("test.rpt", chunksize=1):
    counter=counter+1
print(counter)
```

This seems to work well - however I realized that it is quite slow and to really read all the lines is unnecessary;

Is there a way to get the number of rows without reading each line?

Many thanks

Comment: No this unfortunately does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `.rpt` file format, but if it can be read in as a text file (which I'm assuming it can if you're using `pd.read_fwf`) then you can probably just use Python's builtins for input/output.

```
with open('test.rpt', 'r') as testfile:
    for i, line in enumerate(testfile):
        pass
    # Add one to get the line count
    print(i+1)
```

This will allow you to (efficiently) iterate over each line of the file object. The builtin [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function will count each line as you read it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use python. Using

```
 wc -l
```

would be the right tool for that job.

Comment: I'd like to know whether there is a way in Python... :-)

Comment: Sorry I need to be more precise: I do not have Linux currectly because I was too lazy to work with two systems and with Windows the equivalent command also takes ages

Comment: No need for linux. Use cygwin.